# Jest & Typescript - jest.SpyOn Type Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to use `jest.spyOn` to test a method called on `componentDidMount`. I can't see why the method `onMountFuction` is returning a Typescript error :

> Argument of type '"onMountFuction"' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type

```
class App extends NextApp<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.onMountFuction('The Component Did Mount');
  }

  onMountFuction(msg: String) {
    console.log(msg);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}
```

My Current Test :

```
describe('Test GTM Intergration', () => {
  it('Should Init on ComponentDidMount', () => {
    const Props = {
      initialState: {},
    };
    const AppWrapper = new App(Props);

    jest.spyOn(AppWrapper, 'onMountFuction'); // Argument of type '"onMountFuction"' is not assignable to parameter of type
  });

});
```

Comment: What's `NextApp`, are you using `next.js` or what?

Comment: I agree with @slideshowp2, can you give some context around what NextApp is?